# Checkbox Filter results

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on something similar to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/YEtgM/5/).

What I want to add is that when '1 Bedroom' is selected, any items that have 1 Bedroom should display, even if none of the location checkboxes are selected.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is add an "or" to your statement at the bottom which checks if the array is empty or not.

Keeping your current code structure, the last bit of you code would look like this:

```
$('li').each(function() {
    if (($.inArray($(this).data('location'), loc_array) > -1 || loc_array.length == 0) && ($.inArray($(this).data('bedrooms'), room_array) > -1 || room_array.length == 0)) {
        $(this).show();
    } else {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Of course your code could be re-factored to make it easier to read and (possibly) more efficient. But the purpose of this is to help you understand what you need to do. Re-factoring comes later!

Comment: I tried that already, what happens is then, that when I search for 1 Bedroom and London - It display all items that include 1 Bedroom and all items that include London (Instead of the items with 1Bedroom and London together only)

Comment: Then change the logic slightly. I only offered that as an example of what I thought you wanted. In that case, check both have `length > 0`, if they do, it must be both, if one of them filter to that only, if neither show all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your input change function:

```
var bedrooms = $(this).data('bedrooms');
$('ul > li').each(function(){
    if($(this).data('bedrooms') !== bedrooms) $(this).toggle();
});
```

Comment: Hi tijs thanks for landing a hand. The results need to show results which have checked items in common. Consider I have 1 Bedroom Apartment in London, 2 Bedroom Apartment in London and a 1 Bedroom Apartment in Paris. If I check 1 Bedroom, then the results will show: 1 Bedroom Apartment in London and 1 Bedroom Apartment in Paris. If I keep 1 Bedroom checked and then I check London, then the results would just show 1 Bedroom in London. Meanwhile, if I choose London and no checkbox of number of bedrooms then the results would show: 1 Bedroom Apartment in London and 2 Bedroom Apartment in London.